# Changing MeshRenderer materials array does not update game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a material to a mesh renderer at runtime, however the new material does not appear in game. The debug log shows that the material does get added to the `objRender.materials` array, but in the scene there is no change.

```
private void updateLockMaterial()
{
        MeshRenderer objRender = GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>();

        List<Material> mats = objRender.materials.ToList();
        mats.Add(Instantiate<Material>(lockMat));

        Debug.Log(objRender.materials[objRender.materials.Length-1]);    //Debugging
        objRender.materials = mats.ToArray();
        Debug.Log(objRender.materials[objRender.materials.Length - 1]);  //Debugging
}
```

I have tried using `sharedMaterials` aswell with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the `Material` constructor to create a new `Material` at runtime.

Simply replace

```
mats.Add(Instantiate<Material>(lockMat));
```

instead with

```
mats.Add(new Material(lockMat));
```

The [`Material`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-ctor.html) doc has a lot of other useful information about materials.